# Is there a way to set and merge without creating a map for just 1 value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to add just one more value into my user

```
docRef.document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
    .set("hasShop", SetOptions.merge())
```

Now, I want to say that this hasShop value should be true, but I dont want to do this

```
val map = hashMapOf<String,Any>
map["hasShop"] = true
docRef.document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
    .set(map, SetOptions.merge())
```

Is there a better way to do it like this ?

```
 docRef.document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
    .set("hasShop" {true} , SetOptions.merge())
```

Comment: did you try it with the update instead of set?

Comment: does update will create the field if it does not exists ? I will need to do the same creating the map before right ?

Comment: first, try to use ```update``` if the document doesn't exists add the ```set``` method in ```onFailure```

Comment: The problem is that this field will never be updated, it will be created just once

Comment: can you please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#update(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) to set a value on an existing document.

```
 docRef.document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
    .update("hasShop", true)
```

Comment: The problem Doug is this If no document exists yet, the update will fail. Thats why I used set with merge, because I dont have that field yet

Comment: I think you misunderstand the merge argument.  You only need merge=true if the entire document doesn't exist yet.  You can use update on fields that don't exist on documents that do already exist.